# PHP issue with Gd in WAMP (imagejpeg doesn't work)

Tags: php, gd, wamp

I'm using WAMP 2.2 on windows XP 32bit. I tried to make simple php script, which draws image, but something went wrong and I came back to simple examples from web. But even then images don't show (only "blank-image" icon).

Here's example code (from php webpage):

```
<?php 
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(120, 20); 
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 233, 14, 91); 
imagestring($im, 1, 5, 5, 'A Simple Text String', $text_color); 

header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

imagejpeg($im); 
imagedestroy($im); 
?>
```

Best thing is when I add second parameter in "imagejpeg" method, which is output file name it actually works:

```
imagejpeg($im, "output.jpg");
```

Things I tried/checked:

- php is working (phpinfo())
- gd is working (as phpinfo() says and extension is checked in wamp tray->php->extensions->php_gd2)
- without header line I get raw image data, which proofs gd is working
- tried many other examples, the same result
- tried on other browsers
- tried to restart wamp server
- other php scripts are of course working
- tried to enable/check all available error logs, nothing is showing any error
- tried to use this "image" in "img" html object on other page (the same result - "blank/no image" icon)

Right now I'm out of ideas.

Please help,
Regards ;)

Comment: Did you try making a new file? Maybe you have some sort of caching enabled ..

Comment: Do you mean change php file name? I tried it too. Just installed another browser, doesn't work too so it's not matter of chaching.

Comment: No, server side caching .. If you tried that too .. beats me :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found solution by my own. Php script was saved in "UTF8 encoding", but it has to be "UTF without BOM" (it can be done with notepad++).

So it was issue neither with script or wamp configuration, but just wrong encoding.

Comment: Thanks man for sharing! I was having the same problem for days! It almost drove me nuts, as i also had tried everything you mentioned above! (even re-installing wamp twice!)